# Nginx proxy_pass cannot load asset VueJS

Tags: docker, vue.js, nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I have 3 website and running on docker port 8000, 8001, and 8002.

I'm configuring nginx with this config:

```
server {
server_name my.domain.net;

location / {
  proxy_pass              http://localhost:8000;
  proxy_set_header        Host $host;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}

location /old {
    proxy_pass            http://127.0.0.1:8001;
    proxy_set_header      Host $host;
    proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}

location /new {
    proxy_pass            http://127.0.0.1:8002;
    proxy_set_header      Host $host;
    proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
}
```

It works for location /, but for location /old and /new without all assets. I inspect element, for location /old the assets redirect to http://my.domain.net (absolutely 404 not found), where it should be http://my.domain.net/old/asset.css.

Need advice

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In your `new` and `old` applications hosted at 8081 and 8082 respectively, add [`assetsDir`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#assetsdir) in your configuration.

`vue.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  assetsDir: 'new'
}
```

Comment: I have added assetsDir: 'new' in vue.config.js, and when I access http://my.domain.net/new, I get a 403 forbidden. can you help me?